# Komodo indent arrows not showing up

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

Hi I'm using Komodo edit 9.3 in Windows, mostly for Python scripting:
in my ide I turned on view indentation guide and although I see the vertical lines I cannot seem to get the arrows to show up. I attached a picture and drew two red arrows of how it should look like. thanks in advance. 
Ahdee[image]

Comment: Hi there, Komodo dev here. Are you using a custom color scheme? Try switching to one of the default provided ones. Also keep in mind that whitespace can be toggled on a file by file basis from the "View" menu.

Comment: @Naatan Yes after installation the default had the same problem.  I tried to switch between the defaulted ones but so far it just changes the color scheme but still no arrows ;(

Answer (score 0):

I found out what happen. I have to turn on View whitespace by going to view and selecting it.  For some reason I did not think about doing it since I was focus on tabs.